# Let $\{X_n:n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of r.v. with $X_n\to X$ a.s., then $X$ is r.v

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to understand the "almost sure convergence" concept. I've seen two definitions,

Let $\{X_n:n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of r.v. defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P) $.

Definition 1: Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. We will say that $X_n\to X$ a.s. (almost sure convergence) if $\exists N\subset\Omega : P(N)=0 $ with $\lim_n X_n(w)=X(w), \forall w\in N^c $

Definition 2: Let $X$ be a r.v. on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P) $, then we will say that $X_n\to X$ a.s. if $P(\lim_n X_n = X )=1$

In the second one, we are defining the limit as a r.v., but in the first one, it is not said that $X$ is a r.v. so I have searched if it is (trying not to use the second one).

What I found is to define $X^*(w)=\begin{cases} X(w)  & w\in N^c \\ 0  &w\in N \end{cases} $, then it is said that $X_n\to X^*$. As measurable functions preserves limits, $X^*$ is r.v., and because $X=X^*$ a.s, we have $X$ is r.v. too.

I'm not seeing why $\lim_n X_n(w)= 0$ when $w\in N$. Is this proof correct? I don't think so. The argument satisfies me, but we don't know if $X_n\to X^*$.

Comment: Why is it a problem if $\lim_n X_n(\omega) \ne 0$ when $\omega \in N$?

Comment: @user6247850 Because we're using the result that says if $X_n$ are measurable functions and there is pointwise convergence to $X^*$, that's to say $X_n\to X^*$, then $X^*$ is a measurable function. So, if it is $\lim_n X_n(w)\neq 0$, we can't say $X_n\to X^*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_n\to X$ on $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mathsf{P}(A^c)=0$, $X$ need not be measurable unless $\mathsf{P}$ is complete. On the other hand, $X_n\to X^*$ on $A$, and $X^*$ is measurable, i.e., it is a random variable.

Comment: Then, how do u know that $N$ is a null set, i.e., $\mathsf{P}(N)=0$?

Comment: You're right. So what you're telling me is that in the definition 1 we can't assert $X$ is r.v. unless $P$ is complete?

Comment: @Á.Iborra That's right. However, you can choose the limit to be measurable, i.e., take $X^*$ (or redefine $X$ on the null set $N$).

Comment: What's the difference between $X_n\to X$ on $N^c$ and $X_n\to X^*$ on $N^c$ ? I think there isn't. So why is it $X^*$ measurable?

Comment: $X=X^*$ on $N^c$... But $X^*$ is constant on $N$. In general, a function is measurable if it is measurable on $A$ and $A^c$ separately.

Comment: Also, here is an argument why we need completeness for the measurability of $X$. For any Borel set $B$,
\begin{align}
\{X\in B\}&=\{\{X\in B\}\cap N^c\}\cup \{\{X\in B\}\cap N\} \\
&=\{\{X^*\in B\}\cap N^c\}\cup N',
\end{align}
where $N'\subseteq N$. $N'$ may not belong to $\mathcal{A}$ unless the latter is $\mathsf{P}$-complete.